# ECMAScript differences between ES2022 and ESNext

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I'm developing a TypeScript Node.js project with Next.js.

I have noticed that in the TypeScript configuration file tsconfig.json, it allows me to specify the values of the "target" and "label" fields as ES2022 (ECMAScript 2022) and ESNext (ECMAScript Next). Could someone please enlighten me about the significant differences between using ECMAScript 2022 and ECMAScript Next?

Your insightful information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ES Next is a term for the next version of ECMAScript. There are many articles about what's in ES2023, [one example](https://thenewstack.io/the-new-javascript-features-coming-in-ecmascript-2023/)

Comment: That value is explained [in the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target).